# Converting null value to default value in database

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

How to Update Default Value from Null value to all tables in given database..

Answer (score 0):

Create an `UPDATE` query with `WHERE field IS NULL` and `SET field = yourdefaulthere`.